# VS2010 c# find who is calling my indexer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I was wondering if someone could help me figure out how I can find out what the calling function is to an indexer withing Visual Studio 2010. When I look at the call stack window and expand the indexer I'm watching (expand "Calls to 'this'") it shows "Searching" then says "Search found no results".
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to expand anything. When execution stops at your indexer - you'll see caller in the call stack window right at the second line (highlighted with red outline).

So, put breakpoint in the indexer, run program and wait until execution stops.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Red Gate Reflector also has an analysis tool that will find all callers (via static analysis, you don't have to interrupt the program with a breakpoint).  It used to be free but isn't any longer (If you write .NET software for a living, the $35 is well worth it.  For open source hobbyists, not so much.).  I'm not sure if the free clone ILSpy has that ability.